# remove duplicates in "case when" and calculate average between steps

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am currently generating a table where I am trying to sequence the events of a registration form's journey by sessionid, respectively, the following is my code:

```
create table merchant_general.signup_step_v20 as
select a.sessionid, min(b.sentat) over (partition by b.sessionid) as pageload, 
case when a.properties.itemname in ("MerchantType1", "MerchantType2", "MerchantType3", "MerchantType4") and a.properties.clicktype = 'forward' then max(a.sentat) over (partition by a.sessionid) end as SelectedMerchantType,
case when a.properties.itemname = "Continue" and a.properties.`location`= "Yeni başvuru-mağaza bilgileri" then max(a.sentat) over (partition by a.sessionid) end as EnteredNamePass,
case when a.properties.itemname = "Continue" and a.properties.`location`= "yeni başvuru-başvuru bilgileri" then max(a.sentat) over (partition by a.sessionid) end as EnteredAuthInfo,
case when a.properties.itemname = "Submit" and a.properties.`location`= "yeni başvuru-başvuruyu tamamlayın" then max(a.sentat) over (partition by a.sessionid) end as EnteredCompanyInfo
from merchant.mp_clickitem a 
inner join merchant.mp_pageload b 
on a.sessionid = b.sessionid 
where b.dy >= date_sub(current_date,30) and b.dy <= date_sub(current_date,1) and a.dy >= date_sub(current_date,30) and a.dy <= date_sub(current_date,1) 
and b.properties.pagename = "Register" and
a.properties.itemname in("MerchantType1", "MerchantType2", "MerchantType3", "MerchantType4","Continue","Submit") and a.properties.`location` != "Reset Password" and a.sessionid != ''
```

[image: This is the sample result]
column A corresponds to: sesssionID,
while column B is pageload (the first step),
column C is SelectedMerchantType (the second step)
column D is EnteredNamePass (the third step),
column E is EnteredAuthInfo (the fourth step),
column F is EnteredCompanyInfo (the last step).

I want to calculate the minute difference between two consecutive steps, avoiding duplicating of sessionIDs.It is not possible to proceed to the next step before a step is finished, and different steps cannot have exactly the same timestamp.

The final table should like this:[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want... couldn't you simplify the question? The six steps are needed to understand your issue or just with 2 would be enough to represent it? In addition, you should paste plain text instead images if you want to help us help you

Comment: Can you accept my req at LinkedIn? I can show the whole case better if i can pm you @JaimeDrq

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried grouping by sessionID?